# How can I set the background color on specific areas of a figure?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've managed to plot a series of points with the following code:

```
plt = pp.figure()
for i in range(spt.shape[1]):
    spktrain = spt[0,i]
    for trial in spktrain:
        non_z = np.nonzero(trial)
        non_z = non_z[0]
        pp.plot(t[non_z], trial[non_z], 'bo')
```

I would like to place alternating bands of white and gray background on the figure in order to separate the data from each iteration of the outer for loop.  In other words, I would like the data from each "spktrain" to have it's own background color (the data does not overlap).

How can I go about changing the background color of a figure in a specific region?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You can use `axhspan` and/or `axvspan` like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.xlim(0, 5)
plt.ylim(0, 5)

for i in range(0, 5):
    plt.axhspan(i, i+.2, facecolor='0.2', alpha=0.5)
    plt.axvspan(i, i+.5, facecolor='b', alpha=0.5)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: You can also set these rectangles to be drawn behind your actual plot with `zorder`. For example: `plt.axhspan(i, i+.2, facecolor='0.2', alpha=0.5, zorder=-100)`

Comment: I am drawing a plot similar to the [yahoo finance charts](https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/%5EGSPC/chart). So, I need that the color spans automatically fits the ticks' values. Can you expand your answer to include this aspect? Thanks in advance for any help! =)

Comment: @xicocaio: As I understand it, I think your question is different enough from this so that it would be preferable to ask it as a separate question.

Comment: @tom10 Sure, Thank you for the fast response! Just asked, [here is the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61282135/2464671).