# How can I add an alternating background color when I have dates on the x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've recently started using the **`dark chesterish`** theme from [dunovank](https://github.com/dunovank/jupyter-themes), and I 
love how good a simple [pandas.DataFrame.plot(](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)) looks like out of the box:

**[Snippet 1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html):**

```
# Theme from dunovank, exclude if not installed:
from jupyterthemes import jtplot
jtplot.style()

# snippet from pandas docs:
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000)).cumsum()
ax = ts.plot()
```

**Output 1:**

[image]

But I'd like to add an alternating background color (seems to be all the rage with big news agencies). The post [How can I set the background color on specific areas of a pyplot figure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957637/how-can-i-set-the-background-color-on-specific-areas-of-a-pyplot-figure) gives a good description of how you can do it. And it's really easy for ***numeric x-values***:

**Snippet 2**:

```
# imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from jupyterthemes import jtplot

# Sample data
np.random.seed(123)
rows = 50
dfx = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(90,110,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable Y'])
dfy = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(25,68,size=(rows, 1)), columns=['Variable X'])
df = pd.concat([dfx,dfy], axis = 1)
jtplot.style()

ax = df.plot()
for i in range(0, 60, 20):       
            ax.axvspan(i, i+10, facecolor='lightgrey', alpha=0.025)
```

**Output 2:**

[image]

But it gets a lot messier (for me at least) when the x-axis is of a time or date format. And that's because the axis in my two examples goes from this

```
# in:
ax.lines[0].get_data()

# out:
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
        17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33,
        34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49],
       dtype=int64)
```

To this (abbreviated):

```
# in:
ts.plot().lines[0].get_data()

# out:
.
.
Period('2002-09-15', 'D'), Period('2002-09-16', 'D'),
Period('2002-09-17', 'D'), Period('2002-09-18', 'D'),
Period('2002-09-19', 'D'), Period('2002-09-20', 'D'),
Period('2002-09-21', 'D'), Period('2002-09-22', 'D'),
Period('2002-09-23', 'D'), Period('2002-09-24', 'D'),
Period('2002-09-25', 'D'), Period('2002-09-26', 'D')], dtype=object)
```

`ts.plot().lines[0].get_data()` returns the data on the x-axis. But is there a way to find out where matplotlib ***renders the vertical lines for each 'Jan' observation***, so I can more easily find decent intervals for the alternating black and grey background color?

[image]

Thank you for any suggestions!

---

**Edit - Or is there a theme?**

Or does anyone know if there exists a theme somewhere that is free to use?
I've checked all matplotlib themes `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; print(plt.style.available)` and [Seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/), but with no success.

---

**Edit 2 - Suggested solution from ImportanceOfBeingErnest with the chesterish theme activated:**

[image]

In my humble opinion, this is a perfect setup for a time series chart (could maybe drop the splines though)

Comment: Just concerning your last edit; no, there is no "theme". The reason is that there is no standard artist that could be styled in an appropriate way to achieve the desired alternating shading, but rather you need to create the spans manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gridlines are by default shown at the positions of the major ticks. You can get those ticks via `ax.get_xticks()`. The problem will be that it is not guaranteed that the edges of the plot coincide with those ticks, in fact they are most often dissimilar. So in order to have a consistent shading over the range of the axes, the first shade should start at the edge of the plot and end at the first gridline, then the following shades can go in between gridlines, up to the last, which will again be between the last gridline and the edge of the axes.

Another problem is that the limits of the plot and hence the automatically generated gridlines may change over the lifetime of the plot, e.g. because you decide to have different limits or zoom or pan the plot. So ideally one would recreate the shading each time the axis limits change. This is what the following does:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# time series
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000)).cumsum()
# numeric series
#ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000),index=np.linspace(25,800,1000)).cumsum()
ax = ts.plot(x_compat=True)

ax.grid()

class GridShader():
    def __init__(self, ax, first=True, **kwargs):
        self.spans = []
        self.sf = first
        self.ax = ax
        self.kw = kwargs
        self.ax.autoscale(False, axis="x")
        self.cid = self.ax.callbacks.connect('xlim_changed', self.shade)
        self.shade()
    def clear(self):
        for span in self.spans:
            try:
                span.remove()
            except:
                pass
    def shade(self, evt=None):
        self.clear()
        xticks = self.ax.get_xticks()
        xlim = self.ax.get_xlim()
        xticks = xticks[(xticks > xlim[0]) & (xticks < xlim[-1])]
        locs = np.concatenate(([[xlim[0]], xticks, [xlim[-1]]]))

        start = locs[1-int(self.sf)::2]  
        end = locs[2-int(self.sf)::2]

        for s, e in zip(start, end):
            self.spans.append(self.ax.axvspan(s, e, zorder=0, **self.kw))

gs = GridShader(ax, facecolor="lightgrey", first=False, alpha=0.7)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is great! For some reason I had an issue with disappearing gridlines when I had the chesterish theme activated. The shaded area was there, but no gridlines. Thankfully, a simple `plt.grid(which='Major')` took care of that too. I added a screenshot in the question if anyones interested in the final product with the chesterish theme activated.

Comment: I hope you don't mind a little follow-up question: Your example starts with a shaded area. How would you change your example to start with a non-shaded area? I tried myself, but quickly made a mess out of it all.

Comment: I updated the answer with an argument `first` added. If `True` the first interval is shaded, if `False` it is not.

Answer (score 4):

Use an axis vertical span with datetime values for the x-values:

```
from jupyterthemes import jtplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

jtplot.style()
ts = pd.Series(np.random.randn(1000),index=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000)).cumsum()
ax = ts.plot()

# or an appropriate for-loop
ax.axvspan(datetime(1999, 12, 15), datetime(2000, 1, 15), facecolor='red', alpha=0.25)
ax.axvspan(datetime(2000, 12, 15), datetime(2001, 1, 15), facecolor='red', alpha=0.25)
```

[image: timeseries graph with shaded vertical areas]

Comment: This will often work, but not always, because pandas changes the units on the axes depending on the input date frequency. You can use `ax = ts.plot(x_compat=True)` to *guarantee* this solution works, but the ticklabels will look different in that case.

Comment: @9769953 Thank you for answering! Any Idea on how to get all the way with tje alternating black ang grey colors between the lines?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Do you know if theres any way to read from the plot itself where the vertical lines have been drawn?