# Plotly: How to retrieve values for major ticks and gridlines?

Tags: python, plotly

I'd like to retrieve the x-values highlighted in this plot:

[image]

The plot is generated in a Jupyter Notebook using this snippet:

```
import plotly
import cufflinks as cf
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# setup
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)
np.random.seed(123)
cf.set_config_file(theme='pearl')

# Random data using cufflinks
df = cf.datagen.lines()

# plot
fig = df.iplot(asFigure=True, kind='scatter',xTitle='Dates',yTitle='Returns',title='Returns')
iplot(fig)
```

---

**This is what I've tried:**

With this setup, you can retrieve every x and y value for every series by simply running `fig` in the notebook. But the tick values are nowhere to be found.

I'v also tried digging deeper in `dir(fig)`, and thought maybe the output from `fig.axis` would do the trick, but no:

```
{'x1': {'gridcolor': '#E1E5ED',
  'showgrid': True,
  'tickfont': {'color': '#4D5663'},
  'title': {'text': 'Dates', 'font': {'color': '#4D5663'}},
  'zerolinecolor': '#E1E5ED'},
 'y1': {'gridcolor': '#E1E5ED',
  'showgrid': True,
  'tickfont': {'color': '#4D5663'},
  'title': {'text': 'Returns', 'font': {'color': '#4D5663'}},
  'zerolinecolor': '#E1E5ED'}}
```

There are however other options for the grid and ticks there like `'showgrid': True`, and `'tickfont'`, but the values seem to be "hidden" somewhere else.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data is only available in the Javascript context, and so unfortunately is inaccessible from Python.

Comment: @nocilaskruchten possible feature request for future releases?

Comment: This would be pretty tough to do, technically, but yes, it's something to keep in mind :)