# How to set background color of the plot and color for gridlines?

Tags: python, python-3.x, plot, plotly

Here is my code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')
fig.show()
```

output:

[image]

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29968152/python-setting-background-color-to-transparent-in-plotly-plots) but code from seems depreciated and does not works.

**Question:** How to set background color of the plot and color for grid lines?

Comment: For bgcolor you can set Layout and then use it to define figure Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852866/plotly-how-to-set-background-color-per-data

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This should help

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.graph_objects import Layout

# Set layout with background color you want (rgba values)
# This one is for white background
layout = Layout(plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)')

# Use that layout here
fig = go.Figure(layout=layout)
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 1',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[3, 6, 4],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[1, 0.5, 1.5]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    name='Group 2',
    x=['Var 1', 'Var 2', 'Var 3'], y=[4, 7, 3],
    error_y=dict(type='data', array=[0.5, 1, 2]),
    width=0.15
))
fig.update_layout(barmode='group')

# Change grid color and axis colors
fig.update_xaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', gridcolor='Red')
fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, linewidth=2, linecolor='black', gridcolor='Red')
fig.show()
```

[image]

Sources:

1. [Grid line customization](https://plotly.com/python/axes/#styling-and-coloring-axes-and-the-zeroline)
2. [Background Customization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59852866/plotly-how-to-set-background-color-per-data)

Comment: Is there no way to set it centrally? I mean instead of those two lines for each figure, is there a way to specify it at the beginning of the file and all figures generated in the file will take that property? Is there a way to do this for both x and y axis together in one line instead of two separate method calls?