# Change tickline color in plotly

Tags: python, plotly

So, I have that graph made in Plotly + Dash in python. I really have to stick with that background color because it make sense for my project.

With that in mind, I can't clearly see the ticklines of the graph. How can I change the color of the tickline?

[Tickline color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tvmnf.png)

Thanks!

Comment: See this: [How to set background color of the plot and color for gridlines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62962623/how-to-set-background-color-of-the-plot-and-color-for-gridlines)

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't know the name was gridlines!