# Matplotlib plot winter periods with background polygons

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a time series on top of a coloured background that show when the winter period is.

```py
dates = pd.date_range("2000-01-01", "2004-01-01", freq="D")
df = pd.DataFrame({"y": np.random.random(len(dates))}, index=dates)

f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax.plot(df.index, df["y"])
```

[image]

I want to guide the eye by highlighting the winter periods ("DJF")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a combination of the consecutive function defined by [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353335/9940782) and the [overplotting background polygons SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9957832/9940782) we can acheive the stated goals.

We use the `ax.axvspan` function to plot a span between X1: X2

```py
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
ax.plot(df.index, df["y"])

# plot winter spans in background
# calculate days that are in the winter season (DJF)
# 0 = DJF, 1 = MAM, 2 = JJA, 3 = SON
is_winter = (df.reset_index()["index"].dt.month % 12 // 3) == 0
winter_time_indexes = np.argwhere(is_winter.values).flatten()

def consecutive(data, stepsize=1):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/7353335/9940782
    return np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != stepsize)[0] + 1)

# calculate each consecutive index as a winter period
winters = consecutive(winter_time_indexes)
for winter in winters:
    time_min, time_max = df.index.values[winter.min()], df.index.values[winter.max()]
    ax.axvspan(time_min, time_max, facecolor='C3', alpha=0.5)
```

[image: Plot with background polygons]